# How do I set up physics for mutually-attracting/repelling bodies (planets etc)?

Tags: physics

I want to set up a number of objects which will push/pull on each other using inverse-square laws of attraction and repulsion, so as to model planets, electrostatic forces, etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you are lucky for 100% accurate physics, I don't think Blender is the right tool

Comment: i think it would be a lot easier by just animating manually and/or just by mathematical equations with GN or AN or empties

Comment: GN? AN? How are empties helpful?

Comment: GN = geometry nodes, AN = animation nodes. with empties you can parent a planet to that empty and e.g. rotate the empty on the z axis. By this the planet would make a circular movement. Of course you can make more complex movements with this, that is just an example